# AWK extract lines whith a specific value

Tags: awk, sed

I want to extract line that contain a specific value in a specific field and I want to use variables:

here is my logfile.txt:

```
    165524401            ftr      996544        HGF57             00007654        9744456666          2014100812204920141008122054

    165524711            sft      776445        HGF865             00007874        66677776          2014100812204920141008122054

    165524700            sft      7765445        HG665             00007874        66677776          2014100812204920141008122054


    165524510            sft      776545        HGhhg65             00007874        66677776          2014100812204920141008122054

    165524711            abc      776445        HGF865             00007874        66677776          2014100812204920141008122054

    165524701            abc      776445        HGF865             00007874        66677776          2014100812204920141008122054
```

I want to extract only lines after checking this conditions

field 1 $1 end with O1 or 11.

field 2 $2 not equal to abc.

field 7 begin with value of a variable already declared

here is my code:

```
var = 20141008

awk -F' *\\| *' 'FNR==NR {  ($1 end with 01 || $1 end with 11) && $2!="abc" && $7 ~ /^ *$var/) ' logFile.txt
```

Comment: It would be useful to highlight the problems with your code rather than just to post it and let us work it out for ourselves. Are all of those blank lines in your input?

Comment: there is no blank line in my file but the field are separated like my example file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v var=$var '$1~/[01]1$/ && $2!~/^abc$/ && $7 ~ var' inputfile
```

will produce output as

```
165524401            ftr      996544        HGF57             00007654        9744456666          2014100812204920141008122054
165524711            sft      776445        HGF865             00007874        66677776          2014100812204920141008122054
```

What it does?

`-v var=$var` creates a variable `var` and passes value of shell variable `$var` onto it.

`$1~/[01]1$` selects lines that end with `01` or `11`

`$2!~/^abc$` selects line with `$2` containing `abc`

`$7 ~ var` checkes if the pattern in variable `var`  pattern is persent in `$7`

Now if you want the `$7` to start with the value in `var`, the variable must be initialised as

`var='^20141008'`

Comment: Thank you for your help it works, but the filed $2 must exactly be different to abc,

Comment: exactly be different to abc?. i didnt get you. ftr and sft in output is different from abc right?

Comment: Change it to `awk -v var="$var" '$1~/[01]1$/ && $2!="abc" && $7~"^"var' inputfile`.